# AREPL extension error in VSCode with Python 3.7

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have just switched to VSCode for Python development and have installed the AREPL extension. Upon activating the extension, I am getting the following error:

*Print Output:*

*C:\Users\Mys\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy__init__.py:140: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init*

*Variables:*

When I start editing the code, instead of showing me the real time output, I get:

*'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

Under the extension settings, Python Path has been set to `C:\Users\Mys\anaconda3\pythonw.exe`

I am fairly new to VSCode and the working of path variables. I have not found a solution to this yet.

Comment: Does AREPL expect the `py` launcher to be installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add conda to your PATH:
...\Anaconda,
...\Anaconda\Scripts,
...\Anaconda\Library\bin,
Hope this can solve your problem.
And you can refer to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/f29n16/conda_vsc_import_packages/) page for more details.